# Building Activerecord / SQL query for jsonb value search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

Currently, for a recurring search with different parameters, I have this ActiveRecord query built:

```
current_user.documents.order(:updated_at).reverse_order.includes(:groups,:rules)
```

Now, usually I tack on a `where` clause to this to perform this search. However, I now need to do a search through the jsonb field for all rows that have a certain **value** as in the key:value pair. I've been able to do something a similar to that in my SQL, with this syntax (the data field will only be exactly two levels nested):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            documents
        ) A, 
        jsonb_each(A.data)
    ) B, 
    jsonb_each_text(B.value) ASC C 
WHERE 
    C.value = '30';
```

However, I want to use the current ActiveRecord search to make this query (which includes the groups/rules eager loading).

I'm struggling with the use of the comma, which I understand is an implicit join, which is executed before explicit joins, so when I try something like this:

```
select * from documents B join (select * from jsonb_each(B.data)) as A on true;
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "b"
LINE 1: ...* from documents B join (select * from jsonb_each(B.data)) a...
                                                           ^
HINT: There is an entry for table "b", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

But I don't understand how to reference the complete "table" the ActiveRecord query I have creates before I make a joins call, as well as make use of the comma syntax for implicit joins to work.

Also, I'm an SQL amateur, so if you see some improvements or other ways to do this, please do tell.

EDIT: Description of documents table:

[image]

```
                                                        Table "public.documents"
Column      |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('documents_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
document_id | character varying           |                                                        | extended |              | 
name        | character varying           |                                                        | extended |              | 
size        | integer                     |                                                        | plain    |              | 
last_updated| timestamp without time zone |                                                        | plain    |              | 
user_id     | integer                     |                                                        | plain    |              | 
created_at  | timestamp without time zone |                                                        | plain    |              | 
updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |                                                        | plain    |              | 
kind        | character varying           |                                                        | extended |              | 
uid         | character varying           |                                                        | extended |              | 
access_token_id | integer                     |                                                        | plain    |              | 
data        | jsonb                       | not null default '{}'::jsonb                           | extended |              |
```

Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Sample rows, first would match a search for '30' (data is the last field):

```
2104 | 24419693037                                          | LsitHandsBackwards.jpg                   |        |                         |       1 | 2017-06-25 21:45:49.121686 | 2017-07-01 21:32:37.624184 | box          | 221607127         |              15 | {"owner": {"born": "to make history", "price": 30}}
2177 | /all-drive/uml flows/typicaluseractivity.svg         | TypicalUserActivity.svg                  |  12375 | 2014-08-11 02:21:14     |       1 | 2017-07-07 14:00:11.487455 | 2017-07-07 14:00:11.487455 | dropbox      | 325694961         |              20 | {"owner": {}}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of your tables and some sample data?

Comment: @joanolo I added some more info. I can post the groups/rules description too, but I don't think that would help as much.

Comment: Images are great... but text is far better, as we can copy and play with it.

Comment: Done @joanolo. Formatting was a bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query similar to the one you already showed:

```
SELECT
    d.id, d.data
FROM
    documents AS d 
    INNER JOIN json_each(d.data)  AS x ON TRUE 
    INNER JOIN json_each(x.value) AS y ON TRUE 
WHERE
    cast(y.value as text) = '30';
```

Assuming your data would be the following one:

```
INSERT INTO documents
    (data)
VALUES
   ('{"owner": {"born": "to make history", "price": 30}}'),
   ('{"owner": {}}'),
   ('{"owner": {"born": "to make history", "price": 50}, "seller": {"worth": 30}}')
;
```

The result you'd get is:

```
id | data                                                                        
-: | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | {"owner": {"born": "to make history", "price": 30}}                         
 3 | {"owner": {"born": "to make history", "price": 50}, "seller": {"worth": 30}}
```

You can check it (together with some step-by-step looks at the data) at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1fa6b2d8a20854d0ce930baa059b9d78)*

Comment: Thanks @joanolo. Last question would be how to take your sql query, and put it in a `joins` and a `where` method chain on top of my original query. The query and error I get is: `current_user.documents.order(:updated_at).reverse_order.includes(:groups,:rules).joins("INNER JOIN jsonb_each(documents.data) AS x on TRUE INNER JOIN jsonb_each_text(x.value) AS y on true").where("value = 30")
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "value" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...S y on true WHERE "documents"."user_id" = $1 AND (value = 30...` . Do the inner joins need to alias the columns?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about how *ActiveRecord* will transform your query into the one I proposed. In any case, your *where* condition *should be* `cast(y.value as text) = '30'`. `value`, as returned by `json_each` is of type `json`, and you want to compary it to '30', which means you have to cast it.

Comment: I got it.
First of all, my full query is as follows:
`current_user.documents.order(:updated_at).reverse_order.includes(:groups,:rules).joins("INNER JOIN jsonb_each(documents.data) AS x on TRUE INNER JOIN LATERAL (select value as v from jsonb_each_text(x.value)) AS y on true").where("v = '30'")`

The `LATERAL` allowed me to reference the previous `INNER JOIN` to build a query on that.

Secondly, @joanolo `jsonb_each_text` takes the json and returns it in type text so that the cast is unnecessary. However, both forms would be correct.

Thanks for your help @joanolo!